# Python: Add a column to a crosstab based on value and condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, crosstab

I have a Pandas crosstab created from NumPy arrays of zeros and ones. After creating crosstab by:`ct = pd.crosstab(index=np.array(labels), columns=np.array(cols)` I have a crosstab that looks like:

```
col_0     0     1 
row_0
---------------------
0        618    53   
1        53     79
```

I wanted to add a column in here for error percentages on false positives and false negatives. I added a new column to the crosstab using `ct[2] = ct.apply(lambda row: row[0] + row[1], axis = 1)` which added a column of sum of the first two columns. I would like to add a fourth column that would calculate ct[0][0] divided by the sum for the first row, and ct[1][1] divided by the sum for the second row, and add that column to ct[3]. I tried:

```
for i,y in ct.iterrows():
   ct[3] = ct.apply(lambda y: y[i]/y[2] , axis = 1)
```

but since it executes twice, it will overwrite the column with the 2nd result. I tried using `ct[3][i]` to no avail. Using `lambda y: y[1] if y==0 else y[0]` doesn't work. What is the method for adding a new column to the dataframe / crosstab, with a condition-based calculation on existing values?

Comment: What does your expected output dataframe look like?

Comment: My expected outcome will have two additional columns, the first additional column is a sum of the first two existing columns, and the second is the percentage derived from dividing the [0][0] in the first row, and [1][1] in the second row. Your answer is exactly what I had in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using numpy and pandas:

```
ct[3] = (ct * np.eye(2)).sum() / ct.sum(1)
```

or

```
ct[3] = np.diag(ct) / ct.sum(1)
```

Output:

```
col_0    0   1         3
row_0                   
0      618  53  0.921013
1       53  79  0.598485
```